# BotFramework TurnContext SendActivityAsync "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to use botframework v4 in Azure Functions Powershell. I have this working successfully by just calling the raw REST APIs and using the botframework types like Activity.

Now I'm trying to actually use the framework and adapters proper. However, when I call SendActivityAsync on the Turn Context, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and really no way to find out where that's coming from.

Is there anything obviously missing here, or perhaps another approach to using BotFrameWork adapter I'm missing? I'm trying to adapt the EchoBot sample to Powershell, as the ConsoleBot sample doesn't call http back to the bot framework.

Assume that Activity is real, I know that's not where my null is coming from(it wouldn't let me create the turncontext if it was)

```bsh
    $activity = [JsonConvert]::DeserializeObject(($QueueItem -replace '^---JSON---',''), [activity])

    #Only Process Message Activities for now
    if ($activity.Type -ne 'message') {return}

    $reply = $activity.CreateReply("I got your message that says $($activity.text)")

    $appCredentials = [MicrosoftAppCredentials]::new('c28d55e3-fb0b-4367-b4a6-f00959a54e5b','n=_y:3LsJo/MYAPPSECRETP5')
    $botFrameworkAdapter = [BotFrameworkAdapter]::new($appCredentials, [AuthenticationConfiguration]::new())
    $turnContext = [TurnContext]::new($botFrameworkAdapter, $Activity)
    $turnContext.SendActivityAsync($reply).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

Comment: I gave up and tried to adapt the lowerlevel ConnectorClient with better success